# How to iterate only one value in List<Map<String, Object>>

Tags: java, collections

The following is my input,

```
List<Map<String, Object>> other =   [{money=2, data=abc}, {money=3, data=xyz}]
```

I want to iterate only `money` in each map and ignore data in each map. how to iterate only money

```
  Map<String, Object> finalMap;
                for(Map<String, Object> child : other){
                    for(Object key : child.values()){
                        if(other.contains(((BigDecimal)key).intValue())){
                            finalMap.putAll(child);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Clarify your question. Whats your input/desired output

Comment: `finalMap` is a `List` and does not have the `putAll` method. Please clarify the question please. Provide a [MCVE]

Comment: What's your `originalList`?

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: Dude, you want help. You have to provide sample output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Java 8’s stream api, it would look like this:

```
other.forEach(map -> {
    Object money = map.get(“money”);
});
```

This would iterate over the list and get the key “money” from the hashmap.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (String key : map.keySet()) {
    // your code
}
```

This should do it. In your case, it would be:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> finalMap;for(Map<String, Object> child : other) {
    for(Object key : child.keySet()()) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you understand the question?

Comment: I want value only